# Viewing a whole code block on mobile chat is impossible

Tags: bug, chat, mobile-web

As you can see, I can't view the complete message here:

[image: lol]

Also, I meant mobile, not module :P

Comment: Oh dear, no scroll bar ;)

Comment: Mobile chat is just broken for me honestly - I can't even scroll down to the part where you can type a message... It just isn't scrollable :(